# Modify ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file using bat before deploying SilverLight solution

Tags: batch-file, silverlight, deployment, msbuild, config

my team is developing a silverlight application and we are now switching our solution to `https` on our server but we would like to use `http` locally. So, in the XAP file that results when building the app there is a `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` having the configuration for the web services that are referenced in the project. The issue is that I would like to have some configuration when I am running it locally and have some other configuration when I deploy it. We decided to alter the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` before building because otherwise it would be encapsulated in the `.xap` file. We are using `msbuild` in a bat file to deploy the solution.
The config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinaryBinding">
                  <binaryMessageEncoding />
                  <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="../../PlatformAdminUtil.svc"
               binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"
               contract="PlatformAdminUtil.PlatformAdminUtil" name="CustomBinding_PlatformAdminUtil" />
         </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I wish to change the `<httpTransport/>` tag into `<httpsTransport/>`.
I'm new on scripting in bat files so I need some help on the script that would manage this.

Comment: This looks like XML data, which is not natively supported by batch scripting; hence I recommend a language that does (PowerShell, for instance, or VBScript or JavaScript). Anyway, StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service, so you need to show your own efforts first! For a batch file, good starting points are: [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html); but note that this treats it as a normal plain text file!

Comment: Why does this look like the same question you just asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528614/bat-script-for-replacing-strings-creates-empty-file