# bat script for replacing strings creates empty file

Tags: batch-file, replace, config

I'm using this bat file to modify a value in a web.config from httpTransport to httpsTransport. It works well if I direct my output to another file. If I try to overwrite my file it creates an empty file.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=httpsTransport"
set "replace=http123Transport"
set INTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\Web.config
set OUTTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\WebTemp.config

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"

del %INTEXTFILE%

rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

Any help would e apreciated

Comment: You need to output to a new file.  After the replacement just rename the new file to the original file.  K.I.S.S.

Comment: Yup, found that out, but the renaming just dosen't rename the file....added new version

Comment: I know why...I have my whole path in INTEXTFILE, that is wrong, it should only be "web.config"

Comment: And you saw the error on the screen when it tried to rename a file to a file that already existed.  So what is stopping you from using the delete command to remove the original file first before renaming the new one.  Your other option is to use `MOVE /Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fails in case both `INTEXTFILE` and `OUTTEXTFILE` point to the same file, because the output redirection `>` prepares the output file at the beginning, so it creates an empty file, which is then read by `findstr`:

```dos
set "INTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\Web.config"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\Web.config"
> "%OUTTEXTFILE%" (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Replacing `>` by `>>` does also not work, because this appends the new data to the original file.

---

To overcome this, you have got two options:

1. To write to a different file and to replace the original file by the new one at the end:

   ```dos
   set "INTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\Web.config"
   set "OUTTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\WebTemp.config"
   > "%OUTTEXTFILE%" (
       for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
           set "line=%%i"
           setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
           set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
           echo(!line!
           endlocal
       )
   )
   move /Y "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
   ```

   This is the recommended variant due to better performance.
2. To ensure that the file is read *before* the output redirection is applied:

   ```dos
   set "INTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\Web.config"
   set "OUTTEXTFILE=D:\teste_bat\Web.config"
   for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%INTEXTFILE%" ^& ^> "%OUTTEXTFILE%" rem/') do (
       set "line=%%i"
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
       >> "%OUTTEXTFILE%" echo(!line!
       endlocal
   )
   ```

   This is worse in performance since there are multiple file access operations (appending to the file per each loop iteration due to `>>`), but it prevents the need of a temporary file. The portion `> "%OUTTEXTFILE%" rem/` depletes the file *after* being read by `findstr`, then it is appended to later in the loop body.