# Parse xml file and replace element in batch script

Tags: xml, batch-file, config

I have this config:

```
<configuration>     
    <system.serviceModel>     
        <bindings>     
            <customBinding>     
                <binding name="CustomBinaryBinding">     
                  <binaryMessageEncoding />     
                  <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />     
                </binding>     
            </customBinding>     
        </bindings>     
        <client>     
          <endpoint address="../../PlatformAdminUtil.svc"     
               binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"     
               contract="PlatformAdminUtil.PlatformAdminUtil" name="CustomBinding_PlatformAdminUtil" />     
          <endpoint address="../../EntityAccess.svc"     
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"     
                contract="PlatformEntityAccess.EntityAccess" name="CustomBinding_EntityAccess" />     
          <endpoint address="../../EntityAdminAccess.svc"     
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"     
                contract="PlatformEntityAdminAccess.EntityAdminAccess" name="CustomBinding_EntityAdminAccess" />     
          <endpoint address="../../LogErrorService.svc"     
               binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"     
               contract="LoggerService.LogErrorService" name="CustomBinding_LogErrorService" />     
        </client>     
    </system.serviceModel>     
</configuration>
```

I want to make a .`bat` file that is capable of changing the `httpTransport` element to `httpsTransport`, but only for the binding I want, like provide the name of the binding for witch to rename the element, in this case: `CustomBinaryBinding`. I managed to do this but only to replace all strings `httpTransport` to `httpsTransport` but this is not correct because I could have some web services bindings to `http` and some to `https`.

Comment: Please do not double-post! [Modify ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file using bat before deploying SilverLight solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40527751)

Comment: It's not the same question, I realized that I have to add something to my functionality and I thought I should add another question about it, not modify the current one. The added part is that I need the replace a specific string contained in a specific xml node, not all string, as it was described in the previous question.

Comment: And I think we told you before in your previous questions that Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell have XML capability.  Doing it with a batch file is just a hack.  Now that is coming from someone who does BATCH-FILES for a living on a daily basis.  I am normally a proponent of doing almost everything with batch files except for XML editing.